# Unsubscribe old app topics

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I developed an android application that uses FCM service for cloud messages.
I have 2 different projects for QA and production so I made a gradle task in my project to switch between the "google-services.json" files.
A mismatch occurred and users in production registered topics in the firebase QA project.
I fixed the mismatch and published new APK but users still registered to the QA topics.
How can I remove their QA topics?

Answer (score 2):

If you still have those users corresponding tokens and the list of topics, you could use the [InstanceID API](https://developers.google.com/instance-id/reference/server#manage_relationship_maps_for_multiple_app_instances) to `batchRemove` the corresponding users.